# Android library proguard separately from app

Tags: android, proguard, lib

From what I have read from Android Library
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Android library proguard.conf will be merged with app proguard.conf. This means android library can not be proguarded separately from app? If the library is released independently, how to proguard it?